# Getting the number of frames generated by a nvidia Quaddro GPU

Tags: c, real-time, nvidia, frame-rate

I'm currently developping a program in C for my work. Here's the point :
There is two computers, one is running a 3D simulation (with a GPU Nivdia Quadro). An external module gets the frames from the DVI port of the graphic card, and send it to the other computer via USB3.

The external module can skip frames in order to avoid a lag between the input and the output.

But it's essential for my project to not lose any frame. So I set a lower resolution and frequency to the GPU (Nvidia), thus the external module works faster than the GPU.

But I can't be sure that I received all the frames because the GPU doesn't generate exactly 50fps (or 60, ...), it can be 49fps or 50.5fps.

My question, finally, is : **Do anyone know a software that can measure the number of frames that were generated within a certain period of time ?**